# Dependency uses outdated URL

Tags: java, macos, bazel, zlib, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to clone and build a GitHub repo using Bazel, but a dependency requires an old verson of zlib via an outdated URL. I've already spent a few hours trying to do things like messing with the `/etc/hosts` file and running a web server to get it to work. I've gotten zlib.net to point to localhost, then running a web server on localhost:80 with zlib at the correct path, but that's not working, since the request is timing out.

I've googled it and only about 3 remotely relevant results have popped up, none of which are helpful.

How do I get it to build?

This is the error:

```
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz] to /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/37df51594c7eac8a62dd677a22c5514b/external/zlib/temp16216011345324291299/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz: GET returned 404 Not Found
```

Comment: An incredibly farfetched Java approach may be to add a `SecurityManager` and attempt to override the URL used in the connection. Honestly not sure if this would work but it's just a thought

Comment: I'm having the same problem building a repo. I can't seem to find where that URL is set so I can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is timing out because the request uses HTTPS, which is port 443, not HTTP on port 80. You can use a similar approach to what you are doing (with the `hosts` file) but just run a HTTPS server on port 443.

This can be achieved using tools such as `ngrok` and your current localhost web server.

Comment: I was using HTTPS, but turns out I had something configured wrong with the certificate I was using. I'll mark your answer as correct since it's still relevant.